# Twilio TrustHub TrustProduct Status Enum Values

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I've created a TrustProduct resource. When I read multiple TrustProduct resources, I want to specify the `Status` I'm interested in. Based on the docs, I can see that `Status` is an enum. However, the docs fail to enumerate the values of the enum.

From reading a record back and from the docs, the only values I have identifed are `in-review` and `provisionally-approved`. For example, using the PHP SDK:

```
$trustProducts = $twilio->trusthub->v1->trustProducts
    ->read(['Status' => 'in-review'], 20);

foreach ($trustProducts as $record) {
    dump($record->toArray());
}
```

Which returns the following (when json encoded for readability):

```
{
  "sid": "BUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "accountSid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "policySid": "RNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "friendlyName": "Some Company",
  "status": "in-review",
  "validUntil": null,
  "email": "someemail@example.com",
  "statusCallback": null,
// end so on...
```

I'd like to know what the other possible values are. Looking in the SDK, I can see what the options are and how they are read/set, but there is no further documentation on the enum values. Ultimately, I'd like to specify a statusCallback when creating these resources and it will be difficult to process those calls without knowing what potential values to expect.

See: [TrustProduct properties](https://www.twilio.com/docs/trust-hub/trusthub-rest-api/trust-products#trustproduct-properties)

Answer (score 0):

I received an approval and rejection. With these two values, I think anyone with the same issue should be able to solve the problem I was having. Confirmed values for the enum (there still may be more):

- in-review
- provisionally-approved
- twilio-rejected
- twilio-approved

In the rejection case, you may need to update the Trust Product to resolve the rejection. If you supply an email when creating the Trust Product, the email will state the reason for rejection and what step you can take to resolve it.